Не корректно отображаются данные в react.js
Всем привет. Продолжаю. изучать react.js и вот с какой проблемой я столкнулся. У меня не отображаются фото.  У меня есть react component
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Subjectlist() {
  const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();

  // Fetch subjects data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/subjects/${id}`, { method: "GET" })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setSubjects(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const leftBTNRef = useRef(null);
  const rightBTNRef = useRef(null);
  const tabNavListRef = useRef(null);
  const [canScrollLeft, setCanScrollLeft] = useState(false);
  const [canScrollRight, setCanScrollRight] = useState(true);

  // Function to manage button visibility
  const updateIconVisibility = () => {
    const tabNavList = tabNavListRef.current;

    if (tabNavList) {
      const scrollLeftValue = Math.ceil(tabNavList.scrollLeft);
      const scrollableWidth = tabNavList.scrollWidth - tabNavList.clientWidth;
      setCanScrollLeft(scrollLeftValue > 0);
      setCanScrollRight(scrollLeftValue < scrollableWidth);
    }
  };

  // Add scroll event listener on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const tabNavList = tabNavListRef.current;
    if (tabNavList) {
      updateIconVisibility();
      tabNavList.addEventListener("scroll", updateIconVisibility);
    }

    return () => {
      if (tabNavList) {
        tabNavList.removeEventListener("scroll", updateIconVisibility);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const scrollRight = () => {
    const tabNavList = tabNavListRef.current;
    if (tabNavList) {
      tabNavList.scrollLeft += 150;
      setTimeout(() => updateIconVisibility(), 50);
    }
    console.log(tabNavList.scrollLeft);
    console.log(tabNavList.scrollWidth - tabNavList.clientWidth);
  };

  const scrollLeft = () => {
    const tabNavList = tabNavListRef.current;
    if (tabNavList) {
      tabNavList.scrollLeft -= 150;
      setTimeout(() => updateIconVisibility(), 50);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="tab-nav-bar">
          <div className="tab-navigation">
            <i
              className="uil uil-angle-left left-btn"
              ref={leftBTNRef}
              onClick={scrollLeft}
              style={{ display: canScrollLeft ? "block" : "none" }}
            ></i>
            <i
              className="uil uil-angle-right right-btn"
              ref={rightBTNRef}
              onClick={scrollRight}
              style={{
                display: canScrollRight ? "block" : "block",
              }}
            ></i>
            <ul className="tab-nav-list" ref={tabNavListRef}>
              {subjects.map((subject) => (
                <li className="tab-nav-item" key={subject.id}>
                  {subject.subjectName}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="tab-content">
        <div className="tab">
          <div className="row">
            {subjects.map((subject) => (
              <div className="img-card" key={subject.id}>
                <img src={`${subject.img}`} alt={subject.subjectName} />
              </div>
            ))}

            <div className="right-column">
              <div className="info">
                <ion-icon
                  class="info-icon"
                  name="arrow-redo-outline"
                ></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon
                  class="info-icon"
                  name="chatbubble-ellipses-outline"
                ></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon class="info-icon" name="heart-outline"></ion-icon>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

subjects содержит массив из объектов у которых есть ключи subjectName, img и тд. При итерации для описания в
<ul className="tab-nav-list" ref={tabNavListRef}>
              {subjects.map((subject) => (
                <li className="tab-nav-item" key={subject.id}>
                  {subject.subjectName}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>

у меня все работает корректно, но вот итерация для
{subjects.map((subject) => (
              <div className="img-card" key={subject.id}>
                <img src={`${subject.img}`} alt={subject.subjectName} />
              </div>
            ))}


нет. При чем если не делать  итерацию для
<ul className="tab-nav-list" ref={tabNavListRef}>
              {subjects.map((subject) => (
                <li className="tab-nav-item" key={subject.id}>
                  {subject.subjectName}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>

то в img все отображается. В чем проблема не могу разобраться. Конфликто в css нету. прикрепил скрин что выдает в консоль  subjects 

Как в случае с subject.subjectName сделайте вывод и subject.img, больше чем уверен, ссылок либо нет, либо они битые.

а что Вы имеете в виду "ссылок не будет". Пардон я новичок

Ну или ошибка со стороны фронта - ключ не верный, например, либо со стороны бэка, кривые ссылки или вовсе отсутствие самих изображений, или в целом отсутствие ключа со ссылкой на изображение. Вариантов много, в любом случае, нужно видеть то, что получается уже во время выполнения кода на живом примере. По коду вроде проблем нет, данные приходят, раз выводится subjectName.

Можете после выполнения запроса, где .then((data) => setSubjects(data)), добавить вывод данных в консоль -> .then((data) => { setSubjects(data); console.log(data); }) и показать что там есть. Если данных много, выложите небольшую часть, где будет видно img и subjectName

0: {id: 6, subjectName: 'Армагедон', direction_id: 2, img: '/img/subjects/chessArmagedon.jpg', createdAt: '2024-09-10T19:48:19.937Z', …}
1: {id: 7, subjectName: 'Буллет', direction_id: 2, img: '/img/subjects/chessBullet.jpg', createdAt: '2024-09-10T19:48:19.937Z', …}
2: {id: 8, subjectName: 'Классическая партия', direction_id: 2, img: '/img/subjects/chessClassic.jpg', createdAt: '2024-09-10T19:48:19.937Z', …}
вот данные которые выводятся в консоль

В консоли(f12) смотрите на разметку html, все ли там правильно добавляется, правильность указания пути до изображения и на вкладку сеть - есть ли попытка запроса изображения с сервера по указанному адресу

Я прикрепил скрины. Там все вроде бы работает

Тогда похоже на проблему стилей. Добавьте ваши стили в вопрос. Ну и сами в инспекторе попробуйте поиграться с ними. Похоже на то, что не установлены размеры контейнеров или скрыта часть контента

спасибо сейчас добавлю

@Scripton, если обратите внимание на первый скрин, то увидите, что изображение отображается, его область выделена жёлто-зелёным квадратом. Но данный элемент находится за другим элементом - "меню". Если через инспектор выбрать это "меню" и скрыть через добавление display: none (например), то вполне возможно, что вы увидите свои изображения. Тогда уже будет другая проблема: "как оно туда попало", скорее всего проблема или с родителем(лями) изображений, либо с "меню".

Попробуйте временно убрать ref={tabNavListRef} из первого списка  и посмотрите, изменится ли поведение рендера картинок
